# Не включил учетку администратора и ограничил доступ юзеру

Tags: windows, права

Привет. Может кто сможет помочь. Переустановка винды, конечно же, - не выход.

Вообщем проблема такая, сделал юзеру права опытного пользователя, а по умолчанию в вин7 учетка администратора не включена. И теперь не знаю, как быть. Хочу доступ админа, но ничего не получается.

Answer (score 1):

с помощью chntpw http://kushavin.ru/?p=133она входит в комплект BackTrack http://www.backtrack-linux.org

Answer (score 0):

Для таких случаев существуют специальные инструменты в виде загрузочного диска, позволяющего управлять пользователями, изменять их права и пароли и т.д. Образ диска могу выслать по почте (ибо здесь не нашёл способа прикрепления файлов)

Answer (score 0):

Для сброса пароля скачайте утилиту chntpw с сайта разработчика, [ссылка](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html). Смотрите раздел Download. Вы можете выбрать Bootable CD image или Files for USB install, размер их по 3 Мб.